# How to get a javascript singleton to return data via $.post?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I would like to create a method on the singleton `dp.DatapodManager` so that it loads the data once via $.post, then I can use that data by calling methods on the singleton.

The output of the following code is:

```
111

222
test data
```

What do I have to do to get `dp.DatapodManager.loadDirectly();` to add the contents of the text file to `div#content`?

[image]

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test load</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('div#content').append('<p>1111</p>');
                $('div#content').append('<p>222</p>');
                $('div#content').append(dp.DatapodManager.getTestData());
                dp.DatapodManager.loadDirectly(function(html) {
                    $('div#content').append(html);
                });
            });

            var dp = dp || {
                VERSION : '0.00.05'
            };

            dp.DatapodManager = (function() {
                return {
                    loadDirectly: function(callback) {
                        dp.qsys.loadDataFromExternalWebsite(function(stringBlock) {
                            var lines = dp.qstr.convertStringBlockToLines(stringBlock);
                            var html = dp.qstr.appendBrToLines(lines);
                            callback(html); //never executes, cannot set breakpoint here in firebug
                        });     
                        callback('<p>this is returned</p>');
                    },
                    getTestData: function() {
                        return 'test data';
                    }
                }
            }());

            dp.qsys = {
                loadDataFromExternalWebsite : function(callback) {
                    url = 'http://localhost/webs/dpjs/data/data.txt';

                    var json = '';
                    (function() {
                        var json = null;
                        $.post(url, {}, function(jsonString) {
                            callback(jsonString);
                        });

                        return json;
                    })();
                }
            };


            dp.qstr = {
                convertStringBlockToLines: function(block, trimLines) {
                    var trimLines = trimLines || true;
                    var lines = block.split(dp.qstr.NEW_LINE());
                    if(trimLines && lines.length > 0) {
                        for(x=0; x<lines.length; x++) {
                            lines[x] = lines[x].trim(); 
                        }
                    }
                    return lines;
                },

                NEW_LINE: function() {
                    return '\r\n';
                }, 

                appendBrToLines: function(lines) {
                    var r = '';
                    if(lines.length > 0) {
                        for(x=0; x<lines.length; x++) {
                            r += lines[x] + '<br/>';
                        }
                    }
                    return r;
                }
            };


        </script>
    </head>
<body>
    <div id="content"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't.  Instead, pass a function as that "callback" parameter and have that function do the work as appropriate.

Comment: OK, I pass a function as a callback parameter and am having the function fill `div#content` (code changed above) but it still gives me the same output.

Comment: Could you open it up in the Chrome dev tools network view? Looks like the response is invalid.

Comment: Right, I removed `var text` now. The first part that doesn't work is that second callback is being executed (`<p>this is being returned</p>`) but not the first callback (`html`), how can I get `loadDirectly` to return the html value that it gets from `dp.qsys.loadDataFromExternalWebsite`. The second problem is the ERROR 200 I am getting in my POST, the url is valid and returns text.

Comment: That's really weird. I've pasted your code and tested in on my localhost: the only difference is that the file loaded by $.post is now just a simple text file. It all worked: content of that file was processed and appended to div.

Comment: Thanks @scr4ve, through pasting the URL from firefox to chrome I noticed that I was accessing the .htm file via `file:///C:/xampp/apache/webs/testjq222/testloadlocal/index.htm`. When I access via `http://localhost/webs/testjq222/testloadlocal/index.htm` it then works.

Comment: Ah, the dreaded file:// cross-domain issue. ) Damn them all. )